# python3 - No module named 'html5lib'

Tags: python-3.x, html5lib

I'm running a python3 program that requires `html5lib` but I receive the error `No module named 'html5lib'`.

Here are two session of terminal:

```
sam@pc ~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
>>> import html5lib
>>> html5lib.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/html5lib/__init__.pyc'
>>> quit()

sam@pc ~ $ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
>>> import html5lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'html5lib'
>>>
```

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Seems you have the module only for python 2. Most probably need to install it for python3. Usually use pip3 for that.

```
pip3 install html5lib
```

You can check your installed modules using:

```
pip freeze    (or pip3 freeze)
```

I strongly recommend you to use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for development. So you can separate the different python versions and libraries/Modules by project.

use:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

You can then easily create "environments" using (simple version)

```
virtualenv projectname  --python=PYTHON_EXE_TO_USE
```

This creates a directory projectname. You just switch into that dir and do a

```
Scripts\activate (on linux/unix: source bin/activte)
```

And boom. You have an isolated environment with the given python.exe and no installed modules at all. You also have an isolated pip for that project. Really helps a lot.

To end working in that project do a:

```
Scripts\deactivate (on linux: deactivate)
```

Thats it.

ONe moer thing ;) You can also do a

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to save all needed dependencies for a project in a file.
Whenever you need to restart from scratch in a new virtualenv you cabn simply do a:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installs all needed modules for you. Add a *-U* to get the newest version.